# Docker MySQL container starts and then immediately stops when using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, containers

My project uses ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web APIs to connect to a Mysql database (using MySql 8.0 image). I have dockerised both of them. Here is my docker-compose.yml file shown below with both services connected to the same network bridge.

Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
    backend:

services:
  mysqldbnew:
    container_name: community-db-new
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
     - 8006:3306
    environment:
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbissues
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
    volumes:
     - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql   
    networks:
     - backend
   

  communitydb.server:
    container_name: community-db-server
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}communitydbserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CommunityDB.Server/Dockerfile
    ports:
       - 8002:80
    depends_on:
       - mysqldbnew
    environment:
       - DB_HOST=mysqldbnew
       - DB_NAME=dbissues 
       - DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
    networks:
     - backend
```

Below is my program.cs file

```
using CommunityDB.Server.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));

});


builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

//see in swagger url has the following formats; https://localhost:7128/api/Account/register
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();
```

and below my connection string

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=mysqldbnew;Port=3306;Database=dbissues;User=root;Password=****;"
  }
}
```

The problem i am encountering is when i run docker-compose the server container starts and runs correctly while the mysql container temporarily starts and then shut down immediately.
Please see the log below.

```
2023-11-06 16:02:32 2023-11-06 12:02:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.34-1.el8 started.
2023-11-06 16:02:33 2023-11-06 12:02:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-11-06 16:02:33 2023-11-06 12:02:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.34-1.el8 started.
2023-11-06 16:02:33 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-11-06 16:07:51 2023-11-06 12:07:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.34-1.el8 started.
2023-11-06 16:07:52 2023-11-06 12:07:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-11-06 16:07:52 2023-11-06 12:07:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.34-1.el8 started.
2023-11-06 16:07:52 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2023-11-06 16:02:33 2023-11-06T12:02:33.573139Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-06 16:02:33 2023-11-06T12:02:33.590768Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34) starting as process 1
2023-11-06 16:02:33 2023-11-06T12:02:33.606506Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-11-06 16:02:33 2023-11-06T12:02:33.648451Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-06 16:02:34 2023-11-06T12:02:34.234888Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2023-11-06 16:02:34 2023-11-06T12:02:34.234972Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-11-06 16:02:34 2023-11-06T12:02:34.520305Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-11-06 16:02:34 2023-11-06T12:02:34.551241Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-11-06 16:02:34 2023-11-06T12:02:34.551322Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-06 16:02:34 2023-11-06T12:02:34.553292Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.34)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-06 16:07:53 2023-11-06T12:07:53.119043Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-06 16:07:53 2023-11-06T12:07:53.148321Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34) starting as process 1
2023-11-06 16:07:53 2023-11-06T12:07:53.161445Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-11-06 16:07:53 2023-11-06T12:07:53.233373Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-06 16:07:53 2023-11-06T12:07:53.813800Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2023-11-06 16:07:53 2023-11-06T12:07:53.813868Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-11-06 16:07:54 2023-11-06T12:07:54.088969Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-11-06 16:07:54 2023-11-06T12:07:54.089291Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-11-06 16:07:54 2023-11-06T12:07:54.089332Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-06 16:07:54 2023-11-06T12:07:54.091234Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.34)
```

I have tried the following

1. Deleting the volumes in docker
2. Deleting the images in docker
   & restarting docker
   But the problem still persists.

Comment: How did you install docker on windows? Did you use the WSL2 or Hyper-V backend? It seems like there may be a permissions or access issue with the mounted directory. I would attempt using a volume declared in the compose file (i.e. `volumes:`) and see if that works

Comment: `data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files` suggests this isn't something in your code, and you need to delete the underlying storage (the `mysql-data` directory on your host system).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on a windows host because it say :

```
 Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
```

And it say that there is trouble with files :

```
Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
```

Maybe clean all files in ./mysql-data but you start with empty database. Or check files in this directory where they come from ?